# How to get the ip address of VM and use it to configure SSH connection dynamically in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the IP address of a VM and then trying to use it to establish SSH to that VM. Following is the script:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1

  vars_files:
    - createVmVars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Gathering Vm info.
      vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{vcenter_hostname}}"
        username: "{{vcenter_username}}"
        password: "{{vcenter_password}}"
        guest: "{{guest_name}}"
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
      register: var

    - debug: msg="{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}"

    - name: Establishing SSH connection.
      script: /home/shasha/devOps/scripts/ssh_configure.sh "{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}"
```

Following is the content of ssh_configure.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id $1
```

But when i am running the playbook, I am getting the following error while executing the third task:

**ERROR! 'var' is undefined**

But the debug module(second task) is printing the IP Address.

What can be the possible problem or Can it be done this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also list the version of ansible you're using to get the best help. To specifically answer your question, you need to quote the whole command string:

```
 - name: Establishing SSH connection.
   script: "/home/shasha/devOps/scripts/ssh_configure.sh {{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}"
```

This should fix your undefined variable issue.

That said what you're doing won't work because assuming this is a newly provisioned VM, ssh-copy-id is going to prompt you for a password so you can login and get your newly created (possibly) pub key added to authoized_keys.  Assuming you know the SSH password for the new VM here's what I suggest.

1 - get facts from VM

2 - dynamically add your host to inventory using [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).  Using the IP you got from fact gathering.  Make sure you add your ansible_ssh_password so you can login without being prompted.

```
- add_host: name="{{guest_name}}" ansible_ssh_host="{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{guest_password}}" groups=dynamic_hosts
```

Use built-in ansible modules to move your [public key over](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) (for future playbook use), [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) and execute them in a [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html).  For example your next play would be something like:

```
- hosts: dynamic_hosts
  tasks:
  - name: move over public key
    authorized_key: user=foo key="{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
  - name: copy over script files
    copy: src=scripts/{{item}} dest=scripts/{{items}}
    with_items:
    - foo.bash
    - bar.py
    - thing.pl

  - name: run script files
    shell: "scripts/{{item}}"
    with_items:
    - foo.bash
    - bar.py
    - thing.pl
```

Comment: ansible version is 2.1.0

Comment: And how to use that ansible_ssh_password ?? I m sorry. I am quite new to Ansible;

Comment: when ansible attempts to establish a connection to your new host, which is now part of the dyanmic_hosts group, it will use ansible_ssh_pass (in a sshpass call).  I've updated my answer to be more explicit

Answer (score 1):

See if this works. I haven't tested this.

```
- name: Set VM IP to be used later
  set_fact:
    vm_ip: "{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}"
```

Use `vm_ip` in your task

Comment: thanks @helloV. Actually i am trying to get the ip address of a vm and then after establishing the ssh communication (passwordless), i want to transfer few files to the machine and then execute those on the VM. Do u have any alternate approach for the same ?

Comment: @Shasha99 Use `copy` module to transfer the file (use `unarchive` if you want to copy and untar). Then use `shell` to execute those files. There are other alternatives too.